# Ideas for contacts listing view

Tags: lists, interface, grouped-list

we are working a new interface in our app and we are looking for ideas that has to do with a contacts listing space. There is a big search input centred at the top and we need a box in content to display / list contacts.

So far we have been working on table with row listing. One row for each contact. Each contact has thumb, id, Name (first & last), phone and 3 action buttons.

Comment: What is your actual question here?

Comment: yeah, what you said seems good.  I'd probably say do that

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you there is a purpose as to what these people will be able to do with that contact list or ways that they have to filter it down more.

So, significant metadata about that person would help i.e. tier of customer, last sale, amount owed.  You could have the metadata be dependent on the task being done.  For example, data last payment for a collections department but the same list showing date last ordered for an inside sales group.

Comment: Its patient management system for medical professionals. We used Datatables to list contacts and we focus on name, id, last visit and action buttons. We changed our colums multiple times so far because of people request. The most important thing is as you said, the purpose of use.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for a mobile app?

If yes, I would suggest to separate between Contact information (thump, id , name) and Actions. I think it is more convenient for the user to select the contact first from the list and then select the desired action. At the same time, the contacts list will take less space. This space will give you more flexibility to pick up the suitable view later.